# How to import a localdb into a SSDT project in VS 2012

Tags: import, localdb, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium. I have an MVC 4 internet project. I added a localdb sql server database file to the app_data folder. All works fine.

I added a new SSDT database project. I try and import the localdb into the database project and can't get it to work. First, it doesn't see the db connection strings in my web config. So I click create new connection, then advanced settings. For the server I entered (LocalDB)\v11.0, then I attach the db file and type type the file name for the logical name. I test the connection and it passes.

Now I click start and I get a dialog telling me the "server version or database compatibility level is not supported"

Is it possible to import a localdb database into an SSDT project?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the SSDT project then importing, you should use the localDB database to create the project. Open the SQL Server Object Explorer (SSOX), right click the DB in localDB (you may have to add the server (LocalDB)/v11.0 ), then create new project.